# A non-empty closed convex subset of a Banach space contains an open ball

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In a Banach space $X$, I construct a non-empty closed and convex set $A$. The set $A$ satisfies two conditions:

If $x\in A$, then $-x \in A$.

$\displaystyle{X=\bigcup_{n\geq1} nA}$

Then to my intuition, I feel that $A$ contains an open ball centered at $0$. For each $x\in X$, we always can have $x/n\in A$ for some $n$. Then intuitively I can have many points clustered around $0$.

What is the right way to prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ has an empty interior $nA$ has an empty interior, the theorem of Baire implies that $\bigcup_nnA=X$ has an empty interior. Contradiction. We deduce that there is a ball $B(x,r)\subset A$, the image of $B(x,r)$ by $i(x)=-x$ is the ball $B(-x,r)$ and is contained in $A$ by hypothesis. We deduce that for every $y$ in the segment $[-x,x]$, $B(y,r)$ is contained in $A$ and in particular $B(0,r)\subset A$.